# embedding pictures folder to application on c# forms

Tags: c#, forms

How can I embed the folder containing the images I use in the C# forms application I developed, so that I can open it on other computers, and what should I do with the folder path in the code?

While developing the application, I used the folder path on my own computer, but now I will compile and distribute the application and I do not know how I can open the images on other computers.

Comment: Use a settings file and use the folder dialog box to set the folder when the user runs the app for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't embed the folder in the application. You have two directions available to you.

Firstly, you can add a folder to your project and then add the image files to your project in that folder. Set the `Build Action` of each image to `Content` and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer`. When you build your project, either for Debug or Release, that folder and the files it contains will be copied to your output folder. You can then use `Application.StartupPath` in code to build the file paths, e.g.

```cs
var imageFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, imageFolderName, fileName);
```

You would then need to deploy that folder along with your EXE, which you can do either by simply copying both manually or including the folder in an installer.

Secondly, you can not use discrete files at all but use resources instead. Open the *Resources* page of the project properties and add existing files there. The files will be copied into a resources folder but that is just a source folder - part of the project but not part of the app. When you build, the contents of each image file will be compiled into the EXE itself. A property will be genereated for each one and you can access them in code like so:

```cs
var image = Properties.Resources.Default.FileNameWithoutExtension;
```

If you use the first option then the files can be deleted and replaced after deployment. If you use the second option, the images are part of the EXE so they cannot be modified without recompiling.